# Delete table name in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to remove/delete the name of my table which is "Table2" using Excel VBA. I know how to remove the name by hand, but I cannot figure out how to set the name "Table2" as a name in VBA. I found other questions on this topic but those codes deleted all named ranges and I would like to remove just the table named "Table2".

This is my code that is not working:

```
Sub Delete_Name_Table()

   Dim n As Name

   n = "Table2"

   n.Delete

End Sub
```

Anyone who knows how to set n correctly to "Table2"?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a Named Range ? or a Table, in VBA reffered to as `ListObject`

Comment: To a table which is listed as ListObject

Comment: You want to change the name ? or delete the entire table (with it's data)?

Comment: Delete the name, not the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can backup data from table, delete table and restore data.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngVals As Variant

    Set rng = YourSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range
    rngVals = rng.Value

    YourSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Delete

    rng.Value = rngVals

    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This restores indeed my data and did only delete the name "Table2", I had to use the ListObjects indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Tox Glad I could help

Comment: Can I delete the content of a named table and leave the column names?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good way to make a table to a range. Thus, the name is removed automatically, but the value stays. Like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim tblN        As Object
    Dim rngRange    As Range

    For Each tblN In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        Debug.Print tblN

        If tblN = "Tabelle16" Then
            tblN.Unlist
        End If

    Next tblN

End Sub
```

If you want to remove the data within as well, here is the code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim n As String
    n = "Tabelle2"
    Range(n).Delete

End Sub
```

It will set `n` to a Table name and it will delete it.

Comment: Thanks, this does delete the range and the data but I am looking for a code that deletes the name of table only. The table is set with ListObject.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your post, and you want something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_Name_Table()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Tbl As ListObject

Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- change to your sheet that has the table

' set the Table Object
Set Tbl = Sht.ListObjects("Table2")
Tbl.Name = " " ' clear the name, you need to give it some kind of name

End Sub
```